# Objective-C equivalent to Swift's "Any"

Tags: objective-c, generics

Is there any way that an Objective-C method could operate on primitive parameters without knowing their types? For instance,

```
-(Any)returnFirst:(Any)first notSecond:(Any)second  {
  return first;
}
```

This could then be used like:

```
int a = [self returnFirst:500 notSecond:1000];
char b = [self returnFirst:'a' notSecond:'b'];
```

Comment: Nope. No. Not a thing.

Comment: You can use `id` if you only care for object-types. That won't work for primitives though.

Comment: Objective-C has `id` but it only works for objects. You could use an `NSNumber` wrapper object, return an `id`, use it as an `NSNumber` and then retrieve the value from it.

Comment: [Generic return type for primitives](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5247477)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no equivalent to `Any` in Objective-C. Your example `returnFirst:notSecond:` cannot even be declared in Objective-C.

Answer (score 1):

> In Swift 3, the `id` type in Objective-C now maps to the `Any` type in Swift, which describes a value of any type, whether a class, enum, struct, or any other Swift type.

Source: https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=39